# Echo php code error

Tags: javascript, php

```js
echo 'alert('Your $user_name is already exists, Please try another one!')';
```

When I tried to sign in just to test it display error:-

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Your' (T_STRING), expecting ','
>   or ';'

Comment: Try this
echo 'alert("Your ' . $user_name . ' is already exists, Please try another one!")';